# One form different submit button using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, submit-button

```
<input id="export" name="btnCetak" type="submit" class="buttonPaging1" value="Export ke Excel" onclick="myForm.action='page/frmpenyata_sudah_cetak_xls.php'; return true" />
<input id="cetak" name="btnCetak2" type="submit" class="buttonPaging1" style="width:200px;" value="Cetak Penyata Semula" onclick="myForm.action='page/frmcetak_penyata_semula.php?upd=1'; target='_blank'; return true;" />
```

that is my button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chkCheckBox() 
    {

            $('#btnCetak2').click(function()
            {
                $('#myForm').submit(function()
                {
                    sebab=$('#txtkaedah').val();
                    if(sebab == "")
                    {
                        alert('Sila pilih alasan untuk mencetak semula terlebih dahulu.');
                        return false;
                    }
                    var a=new Array();
                    a=document.getElementsByName("chkCetak[]");
                    var p=0;
                        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                            if(a[i].checked){
                            p=1;
                            }
                        }
                    if (p==0){
                        alert('Sila pilih Nama Pemohon.');
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        var total=""
                        for(var x=0; x< document.myForm.elements['chkCetak[]'].length;x++){
                            if(document.myForm.elements['chkCetak[]'][x].checked)
                                total +=document.myForm.elements['chkCetak[]'][x].value + "\n"
                        }       
                            if(total=="") {
                                //alert("select scripts");
                            } else { 
                                document.myForm.submit();
                                return true; 
                            }       
                    }
                });
            });

            $('#btnCetak').click(function()
            {
                $('#myForm').submit(function()
                {
                    var a=new Array();
                    a=document.getElementsByName("chkCetak[]");
                    var p=0;
                        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                            if(a[i].checked){
                            p=1;
                            }
                        }
                    if (p==0){
                        alert('Sila pilih Nama Pemohon.');
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        var total=""
                        for(var x=0; x< document.myForm.elements['chkCetak[]'].length;x++){
                            if(document.myForm.elements['chkCetak[]'][x].checked)
                                total +=document.myForm.elements['chkCetak[]'][x].value + "\n"
                        }       
                            if(total=="") {
                                //alert("select scripts");
                            } else { 
                                document.myForm.submit();
                                return true; 
                            }       
                    }
                });
            });

    }//endfunction chkCheckBox
</script>
```

my button redirect to the correct page. but the ifelse condition on on.click function does not work. when i click my button , it straight to the redirect page. it not follow the condition.

my form name is myForm.

```
<form method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return chkCheckBox(this);return false;" action="">
------------my code table and checkbox here
</form>
```